# Error installing Nodejs package

Tags: dpkg, nodejs

I needed to install Nodejs into Ubuntu 14.04

For that, I executed the following command in the terminal with reference from following URL:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

As a consequence of the installation process, I received the following output of process:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 nodejs : Depends: libc-ares2 (>= 1.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: libv8-3.14.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

On basis of the above mentioned output, I executed the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

But upon execution of the above command I got following error:

```
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please suggest an appropriate solution.